# EmberJS 2.7 - using a closure action to call a function vs calling that function as an action

Tags: ember.js, closures, ember-components

In Ember with closure actions you can pass a function, like this:

1

```
    <div class="dropzone text-center" {{action (action openFilePicker)}}>   
<!-- this calls a function (no quotes!) -->
    </div>
```

instead of calling an action, like the following.

2

```
    <div class="dropzone text-center" {{action (action 'openFilePicker')}}> 
<!-- this calls an action (quotes!) -->
    </div>
```

In (1) the code backing this component looks like this:

```
  openFilePicker: function () {
    let child = this.$('div:first-child');
    child.removeClass('is-dragging');
    child.html('<h2>Upload GPX Route</h2><div class="dropzone-body-text"><h5>Drag and Drop here</h5>- or -<h5>click anywhere here</h5></div>');
    filepicker.pick({
      container: 'modal',
      maxSize: (5 * 1024 * 1024),
      services: ['COMPUTER']
    });
  }
```

This uses JQuery to remove some elements from the DOM, then calls another function (filepicker.pick) which is in an externally loaded JS file.

In (2) the same code is inside an action:

```
actions: {
    openFilePicker: function () {
        let child = this.$('div:first-child');
        child.removeClass('is-dragging');
        child.html('<h2>Upload GPX Route</h2><div class="dropzone-body-text"><h5>Drag and Drop here</h5>- or -<h5>click anywhere here</h5></div>');
        filepicker.pick({
          container: 'modal',
          maxSize: (5 * 1024 * 1024),
          services: ['COMPUTER']
        });
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of doing this? I understand that (1) is not the recommended way of doing this, but surely (1) makes it easier to access other code in the `component` (like properties of the component, for example). As usual the `Ember` documentation doesn't seem to shed any light on this (not that I can find anyway). All I can find is [this blog post](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/) which makes the point to discourage calling arbitrary functions (otherwise why have actions in the first place?)

So although this question can result in opinions, that's not what I am after. I want to understand what is the `SCOPING` difference between these two approaches? For example, when you are inside the function INSIDE the action, what is the scope difference from the point of view of the JS runtime? Is 'this' the same thing in both cases, for example?

Comment: Why is it easier to access other code of the component? Ember will bind `this` for your actions to your component.

Comment: What if inside the function that is inside the component you want to call another function (say in a dynamically loaded external file that you loaded just for use in that component - a common scenario for add-ons). 'this' is no longer bound, right? You would have to do let myComponent = this inside the action before calling that nested function (I think!)

Comment: @Lux It turns out it doesn't make it easier :) That was my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a difference. Checkout [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/60d3da2fd2653c987ae628432000de1d?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) twiddle.

The only big difference is the action lookup time. While `{{action 'foo'}}` requires `foo` to exist on bound time, this is not a required for `={{action 'foo'}}` (a closure action).

Action calls are bound by ember to the current `this` context. This is basically what the `{{action}}` helper for closure actions does. It creates a new function that calls the original function with `this` being the context when the `{{action}}` helper was evaluated.

If you call another function outside your current function scope `this` will *always* be different.
Its important to understand that `this` is always bound to the function scope.

If you call a function like `myfunction()` then `this` inside that function will be `null`. If you call a function like `foo.myfunction()` then `this` inside `myfunction` will be `foo`.

Make sure that you understand `this` completely. In a nutshell, `this` is no way different in Ember. It's standard Javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great explanation - and the twiddle really helps. For some reason I thought Ember was doing something special with closure actions regarding 'this' but I see now that, as you say, it just standard JS.